# Waterproof shoes or (more comfortable) trainers for walking a lot in Paris in October?

Tags: paris, weather-and-climate, footwear

I'm going to Paris this month and I'm planning to walk a lot from one attraction to another.

Are waterproof shoes a 'must-have' for this or is the rain not too aggressive?

If waterproof shoes/boots are not so important I'll buy comfortable shoes for this trip, like this:

[image: Trainer]

Comment: consider getting "dress" walking shoes - perhaps Mephisto or the like?

Comment: waterproof shoes can be hot when it is not raining (which most of the time); get a proper shoes that you are comfortable walking in them.

Comment: Europe ranges from the Mediterranean to the Arctic and from the UK and Ireland to, er, places where it rains less than the UK or Ireland. Although your question body clarifies that you mean Paris, your title is essentially meaningless.

Comment: I walk places all the time, in the rainy UK.
I don't wear waterproof shoes.
I can't say it's ever really been a problem, except when its so wet that you get wet everywhere, or I don't watch where I am stepping.